# Google Analytics visitor flow shows drop-offs for homepage

Tags: google-analytics

I checked the visitors flow on my Google Analytics account. It shows drop-offs from the homepage and the group details don't really give much info. The group details for other pages do show that the reason for the drop-offs (at that particular node) are broken links.

Its only the homepage where I don't see any details. Could it be that other external sites are linking to the wrong page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of drop off should, give-or-take, match the exit and bounce figures for your homepage.

Comment: I just checked and it does make sense now.. Thank you
I was just worried maybe there were other reasons that I was unaware of.

Comment: @lancebridge no worries.